# Apps change their positions whenever the phone is rebooted

Tags: rooting, app2sd, sony-xperia-arc

After rooting my phone, I forced some applications to be transferred to the SD card using *DroidSail*, I wasn't able to transfer them before rooting. However, after moving them, whenever I reboot the phone, these apps change their positions in the apps pages.
For example, *WhatsApp* is one of these applications which after being forced-transferred to the SD card, keeps changing it's location every time I restart the phone. The problem is gone when I moved it back to the phone memory.
My Question is: Is there any way so that these applications remain on the memory card, and yet don't change their positions upon restarting ? 'trying to save some internal memory here'

Android Version : 4.0.4
Model Number : LT18i - "Xperia Arc S"

Comment: I guess that's because they are only found after the app drawer is already initialized (the SDCard usually is mounted *after* the `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast). If that's the culprit, I'm afraid there's not much you can do. Does "change position" mean they go to the end of the list? That would be one indicator for this.

Comment: I remember yes they went to the end of the list. Anyways I moved them back to the phone memory, guess that is the only available solution.
thanks :)

Comment: As you confirmed my guess, I summed things up in an answer. If you find that answer helpful, please show so by upvoting (pushing the "up" arrow) and/or accepting (pushing the checkmark below the "down" arrow) it ;)

Comment: can't vote up cause I need at least 15 reputation, which I  don't have yet. sorry!

Comment: Confirmed for the upvote. You still can accept :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you described the app icons are placed at the end of the list, the most likely reason lies in the order of things done during the boot process:

The SDCard is mounted *after* the system broadcasts its `BOOT_COMPLETED` event, so apps moved to the card become visible later than those installed on device storage. With a little unlucky timing, the app drawer is already initialized before mounting of the SDCard is completed, so those apps are added *afterwards*, and thus to the end of the list (as it, btw, is probably done as well with apps you install).

There are multiple solutions to this: Of course, you can move those SDCard-installed apps back to device storage, but that's not always an option (especially with only little device storage available on some devices). Alternatively, you could simply check a different launcher, as not all launchers behave the way described. Many launchers I've tried automatically sort the app drawer, so even when I've just installed a new app it appears normally in alphabetical order.

Comment: What's meant by launcher?!

Comment: In easy words: Launcher is the app running your "homescreen". The word was most likely chosen as you launch most of your activities from here: it shows your widgets and shortcuts, gives you the button to open the app drawer, etc. To name two references, take a look at [Apex Launcher](http://www.appbrain.com/app/apex-launcher/com.anddoes.launcher) and [Nova Launcher](http://www.appbrain.com/app/nova-launcher/com.teslacoilsw.launcher), two of the most famous launchers currently.